# deleted EFI partition by mistake, cant boot to ubuntu

Tags: uefi

while installing arch Linux I deleted the EFI partition by mistake. Arch Linux was installed successfully and I made **new EFI** partition when installing arch linux. I can boot to Arch Linux.

When I select Ubuntu in grub, I enter in *emergency mode* and GUI is not started, instead I get single user mode.

Comment: How does archlinux is able to boot without ESP partition ? do you use Legacy Bios mode ? What version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I made new EFI partition while installing arch linux, i can boot to arch linux but not Ubuntu as described in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Arch Linux made new EFI partition, I just had to update the new UUID of this partition in the `/etc/fstab` of Ubuntu installation which can be done by live booting and edit the file.

A point to conclude here is that EFI partition made by one linux distro can be used by other.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Arch hasn't set up its GRUB to handle Ubuntu properly. In a sense, that's an Arch problem, not an Ubuntu problem; but I do have a suggestion for how to repair the problem using Ubuntu:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from the downloaded files.
3. Boot to your rEFInd medium.
4. Test rEFInd's ability to boot both Arch and Ubuntu. Ubuntu is the priority. Depending on how you installed, you might be able to boot by selecting a kernel and hitting the Enter key; or you might need to hit F2 or Insert twice and add a `root={whatever}` option, where `{whatever}` is a partition device filename, LVM device filename, or UUID number. Entering boot options is most likely to be required if you used a separate `/boot` partition, but Arch is weird in its kernel naming and so it may require adding an explicit `initrd={initrd-file}` option to work, too.
5. If you can boot either OS, back up your EFI System Partition (ESP). A file-level backup (using `cp` or `tar`) to a USB flash drive should be sufficient.
6. At this point:

   - If Ubuntu boots from rEFInd but Arch doesn't, try re-installing GRUB from Ubuntu. Note that you'll need to adjust `/etc/fstab` to mount your new ESP at `/boot/efi` and then run `sudo grub-install`.
   - If Ubuntu and Arch both boot from rEFInd, you can do as above; or you can install rEFInd from its PPA or Debian package and use it as your primary boot manager instead of GRUB.
   - If Arch boots from rEFInd but Ubuntu doesn't, or if neither OS boots from rEFInd, then you've got a bigger problem. I recommend running [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), posting its `RESULTS.txt` file to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and posting the URL to your file here.

Note that re-installing GRUB from Ubuntu is something of a gamble, particularly with respect to its ability to boot Arch. The worst *likely* scenario is that re-installing GRUB in this way will reverse your problem -- you'll be able to boot Ubuntu but not Arch. It's conceivable it will make everything much worse, though. That's where the ESP backup comes in handy; if you make things work, you can restore your ESP to its current state using an emergency system, and with any luck it will begin to work as it does now and you'll be able to try something else.